# Chrome / Flash problems

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, flash, netflix, amazon

I just installed 12.04 LTS on my mother's Dell Inspiron 660s (all standard hardware straight from the factory except some extra RAM). I did this because she hated the Windows 8 that came standard on it, and it had become super buggy/corrupt and experienced BSOD's, freezing, and general crashes about three times an hour. The computer is in her kitchen and is used almost exclusively for Facebook games and watching Amazon and Netflix videos, i.e. It needs flash.

From all the articles I could find on here (most of which are over a year old), they suggest using Chrome or installing/reinstalling flash. I installed Chrome, Netflix and Amazon don't work at all, but YouTube will. I uninstalled then reinstalled flash, I got the restricted repositories or whatever, and have done just about everything I could to try to get flash to work. 
How do I get flash to work?

Answer (score 0):

Netflix uses Microsoft's Silverlight plugin for their browser, not Flash...  As for Amazon, what doesn't work ? their movie service ? or the site in general ?

What you could try is to run Firefox/Chrome under Wine which means you are running a Windows version of the software and it will be able to use the Silverlight plugin that should let you play netflix/amazon movies with their quirky DRM...

http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu

Comment: Just videos. No videos other than youtube work. Also, I can try wine I guess.. but my mom isn't that computer savy, that and this machine might not have the processing power to do it. I am really hoping there is just some way to make it just work. Is there some OSS that is just like a flahs/silverlight/java/whatever replacement. Something like VLC is for media players?